# Assigning a datasource for each Lookupedit that in the cell

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, gridlookupedit

We are using DevExpress tool for our desktop project. One of our columns has a lookupedit control.  However we want to assign different datasources for each lookupedit that in the cells. Is possible? Because every datasource should take a different datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two approaches to accomplish this task:

1. If all your data sources are subsets of one main data source, then use the solution described here:

[Q520399](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q520399)

2. Otherwise, create the required number of RepositoryItems and pass them to required rows as described here:

[Q578980](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q578980)

[Assigning Editors to Individual Cells](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument747)

Comment: The latest link that you give helped us. Thanks.